# GeoTools UnsatisfiedLinkError in display raster layer of RPF data

Tags: raster, gdal, java, geotools, rpf

Background: [Used this tutorial as base](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html)

System: Eclipse IDE in Windows 10 VM

So I have some RPF data that I'd like to display within a JFrame. Right now I'm trying to figure out a way of just displaying a single file (.i42) within a layer and then my next object is to display a image mosaic populated by multiple files of the same type.

It looks like I'll need to use RPFTOCFormat class to get a Reader to build the layer. Using Maven to import the library, my pom.xml (relevant section only) is the following:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>19-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-imageio-ext-gdal</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Within my code (very similar to the tutorial referenced above) I try and use this Reader to build a GridReaderLayer to populate my map with.

```
private void getLayersAndDisplay() throws Exception {
    List<Parameter<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Parameter<>("image", File.class, "Image", //element id and label before file path box
            "GeoTiff or World+Image to display as basemap", //description below file path box
            new KVP(Parameter.EXT, "tif", Parameter.EXT, "jpg"))); //expected file extensions
    //list.add(new Parameter<>("shape", File.class, "Shapefile", "Shapefile contents to display",
    //      new KVP(Parameter.EXT, "shp")));



    JParameterListWizard wizard = new JParameterListWizard("Image Lab", 
            "Fill in the following layers", list);

    int finish = wizard.showModalDialog();

    if(finish != JWizard.FINISH) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    File imageFile = (File) wizard.getConnectionParameters().get("image");  //get path from associated element id
    //File shapeFile = (File) wizard.getConnectionParameters().get("shape");
    //displayLayers(imageFile, shapeFile); //display those layers from file objs
    displayLayers(imageFile);
}

private void displayLayers(File rasterFile) throws Exception {
    AbstractGridFormat format = new RPFTOCFormat();

    reader = format.getReader(rasterFile);

    final MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Jonathan's attempt");

    Style rasterStyle = createRGBStyle();
    Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(reader, rasterStyle);

    map.addLayer(rasterLayer);


    frame = new JMapFrame(map);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.enableStatusBar(true);
    frame.enableToolBar(true);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Raster");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

However when I run the class, I get the following error:

```
it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL
WARNING: Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path
```

I thought I imported the lib via that dependency specified within the maven pom but apparently I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [these instructions](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows) (sans python portion) and after removing gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll and gdal_MrSID.dll from GDAL_JAVA_PATH dir, things began to work. I removed these dlls because despite their presence ([per this)](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/3755), I was getting the following error when running gdalinfo --version

> gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll 126: The specified module could not be found.

After removing the files from the dir, I was able to run gdalinfo --version without issue. Not sure what caused that error to begin with--may need those plugins installed.

Once I updated my Environment Variables and PATH I was able to run my eclipse project to run my class. I got an exception however saying that the provided input was not supported by the reader. [This page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ogdi.html) says that RPF data is natively supported by GDAL. I will probably post in another question as it's a separate issue from this question.

It also bears mentioning that I was incorrectly selecting the .i42 file to load into the reader, when I should have been selecting the A.TOC file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#installing-gdal-native-libraries) implies that you need to install the native libraries as well as the Java module that maven handles. It also states:

> Warning: If you are on Windows, make sure that the GDAL DLL files are on your PATH. If you are on Linux, be sure to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to refer to the folder where the SOs are extracted.

So you may need to adjust the Windows path to make sure you include the dlls.

Finally, I don't see RPF listed on the [supported formats list](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#gdal-image-formats) so you may need to add some code to support that format.

Feel free to add some links and/or text to the GeoTools page that should probably include this information.

Comment: So I downloaded a precompiled gdal/mapserver pkg from here: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php (MSVC 2013-win32)

Comment: I then updated my path to point to the extracted gdal.jar and dll's (within map\gdal of extracted folder) and got the following error: WARNING: Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6\bin\gdal\java\gdaljni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: GDAL native libraries are not available.

Comment: As for support of the format: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#RPFTOC and http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/coverageio/gdal/rpftoc/RPFTOCReader.html were the reason I think the format should be able to be read and displayed

Comment: forgot to mention that I included the apps and plugin directories within the aforementioned package in my PATH as well